# Merging list concurrently - Which is better, CopyOnWriteArrayList or ConcurrentLinkedQueue?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, copyonwritearraylist

Support there are a couple of threads running query tasks which each of them will return a `list` as result, which data structure will be faster to merge the results?

[ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html)

> An unbounded thread-safe queue based on linked nodes. This queue orders elements FIFO (first-in-first-out). The head of the queue is that element that has been on the queue the longest time. The tail of the queue is that element that has been on the queue the shortest time. New elements are inserted at the tail of the queue, and the queue retrieval operations obtain elements at the head of the queue. A ConcurrentLinkedQueue is an appropriate choice when many threads will share access to a common collection. Like most other concurrent collection implementations, this class does not permit the use of null elements.
>   **This implementation employs an efficient "wait-free" algorithm based on one described in Simple, Fast, and Practical Non-Blocking and Blocking Concurrent Queue Algorithms** by Maged M. Michael and Michael L. Scott.

[CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)

> As name suggest CopyOnWriteArrayList creates copy of underlying ArrayList with every mutation operation e.g. add or set. Normally CopyOnWriteArrayList is very expensive because **it involves costly Array copy with every write operation** but its very efficient if you have a List where Iteration outnumber mutation e.g. you mostly need to iterate the ArrayList and don't modify it too often.

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: The whole approach of several threads merging their output into a shared data structure is flawed. Optimal systems never do that; instead they have a downstream thread which accepts the partial results from several threads over a concurrent queue and then merges in a single batch operation.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik this would exclude a scenario where you have long-lived threads and want to inspect results as they are being generated, instead of waiting for a final batch operation

Comment: @tucuxi Given OP's description, that would be perfectly fine. Two queries run and each returns a list.

Comment: Support there's a query method `List<City> getCityListByIds(List<Long> idList)`, the `idList` may be very big, so the query may be very slow. So I split the big `list` to a few little `list` and warp them as  `Callable` tasks and then submit them to a `ThreadPoolExecutor`. That's why I have this question. Sorry for my poor english. @MarkoTopolnik @tucuxi

Comment: You are pretty much describing what Java Streams API is best at: data parallelization. You should try using that.

Comment: @Kayaman I think `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` may be faster, so I run a simple test. But the result show that `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is faster. I'm not sure if my test code was right because you know that it is hard and subtle to write a **correct** concurrent test.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik The `Java Streams API` seems be the feature of `Java 8`, I can only use `Java 7` in my work now.

Comment: Why do you need a concurrent data structure to merge those lists as @MarkoTopolnik suggests? You can save on concurrent accesses by returning sub-lists of cities and mergeing into a simple ArrayList in your getCityListByIds method. It will also waste less memory then a CopyOnWriteList implementation.

Comment: Yes, you can collect all partial results from Futures and merge them in the thread that initiated the query.

Comment: @bashnesnos Merging the results in the main thread needs to wait for all tasks completing. Just thought merging in the sub-threads may be faster.

Comment: Check out `ExecutorCompletionService`, you can collect the results as soon as they are ready, all in the main thread.

Comment: Think about it this way: anyway you have to wait for all your sub-threads to finish, since your results are not ready. So you're trying to save on merging lists concurrently in your sub-threads, rather than merging in your main thread. Concurrent operations would cost more anyway due to synchronization costs, and you can merge results in your main thread as soon as any of your sub-thread is finished (by checking Future.isDone() in a loop for example) so you won't miss too much time waiting for all your threads to finish before you can start merging.

Comment: The question is mostly academic unless OP explains how long the result-lists are, how large the end-result list will be, and other practical constraints. Even then, if the only decision is between CLQ and COWAL, why not time several times on a similar-to-observed load and choose the best?

Answer (score 5):

The `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` allows you to write, wait-free, very efficiently. It will be slower than the `CopyOnWriteArrayList` for reading, but not by much. It will require slightly more space (less pointers all around).

The `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is slightly more compact and provides faster reads, but requires full copies on writes, which is expensive.

Merging (assuming you do not care about ordering or duplicates) is a write-only operation, so you should choose the **ConcurrentLinkedQueue**.

Comment: Yes, I do not care about ordering or duplicates.

Comment: I just read the source code of `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. And yes it requires full copies on writes. But when we copy a list we will use the `addAll()` method, which will use the `System.arraycopy()` API to do a batch copy on array, it's very efficient.

Answer (score 2):

If your query tasks really **return** a list, then it will much faster to merge the results in a single thread using a normal ArrayList.

Comment: I understood that the threads were trying to concurrently fill a "results" list

Comment: @tucuxi Every task will return a `list` as a result.